# Firewalld DNAT Subnet translation

Tags: networking, firewall, subnet, firewalld

I want to translate subnets using firewalld.

I have a ethernet interface, that should translate incomming packets targeting
`192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.178.0/24`.

My home network is `192.168.8.0/24`

I basically want to add a rhich rule like this (cmd doesnt work!):

`firewall-cmd --zone=myzone --add-rich-rule 'rule netmap any from="192.168.8.0/24" to="192.168.178.0/24" with dst="192.168.1.0/24'`

Which is the missing piece to complete this rule? I took a look at the firewalld documentation and didnt find anything.

Comment: Hmm I'm not aware that firewall(-cm)d supports something called `netmap`. But my wild guess is that `from` here refers to the scope of packet source address (e.g. `0.0.0.0/0`, or `192.168.8.0/24`), and `to` refers to that of the original destination address (i.e. `192.168.1.0/24`), and `dst` refers to the desired translation (i.e. `192.168.178.0/24`).

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's even a way to do single-address-pair DNAT in firewalld (other than maybe abusing the `forward-port` directive). The only semi-official way that I've found to achieve what you want is `--direct`:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.178.0/24
```

The thing is not only `--direct` is considered deprecated, it doesn't even use nftables (like the other parts of firewalld) as the backend. It's literally just a pointless wrapper of `iptables`.

You can also by some means "side-load" an extra nftables table:

```
table ip meh {
    chain netmap {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.8.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.1.0/24 dnat to ip daddr & 255.255.178.255 | 0.0.178.0
    }
}
```

P.S. To be frank, IMO firewalld sucks. To me it just annihilates the flexibility of nftables without making anything simpler / easier / more understandable (a.k.a. for nothing).